# Amount of 3-cycle in complete graph.

Tags: graph-theory

Consider the complete graph $ K_n $ .

How much is disjoint cycles of length three?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall interpret disjoint as edge-disjoint. [This question was already considered at MatOverfolw](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81414/how-many-edge-disjoint-cycles-of-length-3-are-in-the-complete-graph). I can remark that the graph $K_n$ has ${n \choose 2}$ edges, so it can have at most ${n \choose 2}/3$ disjoint 3-cycles. I expect that this upper bound differs from the exact value by $o(1)$.

Comment: Your link doesn't go to MO, it comes right back here.

Comment: Oops. Corrected.